# Custom dbgrid and Picklist issue

Tags: delphi, subclassing, dbgrid, picklist

I'm creating my own DBGRid, and it works fine , except of the pick list. whatever button style is set for the grid, it always shows the inplace editor , neither the pick list nor the ellipse button !

i can not figure the mistake I'm doing :( . here is the relevant code :

```
function TMyDBGrid.CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit;

begin
result:=TInplaceEdit.Create(self);

end;

function TMyDBGrid.GetEditStyle(ACol, ARow: integer): TEditStyle;
begin
 case Columns[ACol].ButtonStyle of
  cbsAuto : Result:=esPickList;
  cbsNone : result:=esSimple;
  cbsEllipsis : result:=esEllipsis;
end;
end;
```

And the constructor and destructor just call **inherited** , with the constructor  just setting some colors for the grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason there's no pick list or button is that you are using an `TInplaceEdit` as the cell editor which does not support the functionality you need.

The `TDBGrid` uses an `TDBGridInplaceEdit` that inherits from `TInplaceEditList` as its in place editor which integrates a `TCustomListbox` for its drop down list and paints and manages the edit button.

Comment: but there is a problem : i tried to use TDBGridInplaceEdit , but it is declared in the implementation part of the DBgrids unit . is there any way to use it beside altering the Delphi source ?

Comment: @DrW - That's indeed a problem. You may try deriving your inplace editor from TInplaceEditList, which is closer to the TGridInplaceEdit, and than add the missing functionality by looking at the VCL source for TGridInplaceEdit. But I'm not sure that's gonna work either, there are hard-casts in the dbgrid source that cast the editor to a TGridInplaceEdit.

Comment: Consider asking a question about the problem you are actually trying to solve. There may be other ways then to replace the editor.